# Elasticsearch synonyms for alphanumeric word

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, opensearch

I have a scenario where I need to map the below synonyms with elasticsearch

```
12v => 12 volts, 12 volt
6v => 6 volts, 5 volt 
12.6v => 12.6 volts, 12.6 volt
```

There could be any number of combinations with volts.

I am not sure about the number of combinations that could be there. Is there any way to add synonyms with patterns like (numeric*v => numeric volts, numeric volt)